# How to remove rows with uncorrect id in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using python3. I would like to remove incorrect id's from my dataframe column.

Example:

```
d = {'name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'id': [9356622,9030321,9408530, 1112200]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I need to verify id by multiplying each of the first six digits by a factor of 2 to 7 corresponding to their position from right to left. For example, for id 9356622:
(9×7) + (3×6) + (5×5) + (6×4) + (6×3) + (2×2) = 152. So in this case last number 2 so it's correct since the last number of id 9356622 is 2. I need to check with the last number after preforming this calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def fun_IMO(string):

    try:
        pattern = r"([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])"
        regexFinder = re.compile(pattern)
        string = string.lower()
        res = regexFinder.search(string)
        if res.groups():
            try:
                nuberIMO = res.groups()[0]
                numberIMO_calc = (int(nuberIMO[0])*7) + (int(nuberIMO[1])*6) + (int(nuberIMO[2])*5) + (int(nuberIMO[3])*4) + (int(nuberIMO[4])*3) + (int(nuberIMO[5])*2)
                if str(numberIMO_calc)[-1] == nuberIMO[0]:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
            except Exception as e:
                return e
    except Exception as e:
        return e
```

Answer (score 1):

Input data:

```
>>> df
  name       id
0    a  9356622
1    b  9030321
2    c  9408530
3    d  1112200
```

Explode the `id` numbers to digits:

```
df1 = df['id'].astype(str).map(list).apply(pd.Series).astype(int)
```

```
>>> df1
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6
0  9  3  5  6  6  2  2  # 152 -> modulo(10) = 2 -> True
1  9  0  3  0  3  2  1  # 91  -> modulo(10) = 1 -> True
2  9  4  0  8  5  3  0  # 140 -> modulo(10) = 0 -> True
3  1  1  1  2  2  0  0  # 32  -> modulo(10) = 2 -> False
```

Now check your math operation:

```
>>> df1.iloc[:, :6].mul(range(7, 1, -1)).sum(axis=1).mod(10) == df1.iloc[:, 6]
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: My column id is a object data type, sorry for incorrect code. 
I would need something that will allow me to operate in the same dataframe and not to create a new dataframe since I have 10 columns I need in my original data set.
This output gives me new dataframe with one column and I need to add some new column to my original dataframe or drop records that are incorrect.

Comment: I'm trying to do this:  

df['new_col'] = df.id.str.slice(0,6).mul(range(7, 1, -1)).sum(axis=1).mod(10) == df.id.str.slice(-1)

But it's not working.

Comment: I will use your example and merge two df on index. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe it does not work for your code but it works on your sample. You should accept the answer for other users or edit your question and I update my answer.

Comment: As I said : I will use your example and merge two df on index. Thank you for your help.